# Error Invalid argument supplied for foreach( )

Tags: php

Error_log

> [16-Aug-2013 20:41:33 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/public_html/acp/includes/templates/character.php on line 9

My Character.php

```
<?php
    if (!isset($included) || !$included) exit();

    $buttons = "";
    $empty = true;

    $characters = $_handlerGameServer->fetch($_queryGame['characters'],array($session->get("account")));

    foreach ($characters as $character) {
        $buttons .= "<button class='buttonProcess' name='select_character' title='character_id' value='".$character[0]."'>".$character[1]."</button>\n";
        $empty = false;
    }

    if (!$empty)
        $_templatePage->replace("buttons",$buttons);
    else
        $_templatePage->replace("buttons",$_lang['error']['noCharacters']."<br /><a href='?page=select_server' class='linkProcess' name='unset_server'>".$_lang['character']['changeServer']."</a> | <a href='?page=account' class='linkProcess' name='logout'>".$_lang['character']['logout']."</a> ");
?>
```

Comment: `$characters` is not an array so the `foreach` loop cannot process it. There's not enough information here to answer your question without seeing the function `$_handlerGameServer->fetch()`.

Comment: What does `var_dump($characters)` show?

Answer (score 0):

If your function returns false or empty you can probably do:

```
if($characters = $_handlerGameServer->fetch($_queryGame['characters'],array($session->get("account")))) {

    foreach ($characters as $character) {
        $buttons .= "<button class='buttonProcess' name='select_character' title='character_id' value='".$character[0]."'>".$character[1]."</button>\n";
    }

    $_templatePage->replace("buttons",$buttons);
} else {
    $_templatePage->replace("buttons",$_lang['error']['noCharacters']."<br /><a href='?page=select_server' class='linkProcess' name='unset_server'>".$_lang['character']['changeServer']."</a> | <a href='?page=account' class='linkProcess' name='logout'>".$_lang['character']['logout']."</a> ");
}
```